# Implementation of the heap in the Java Memory Model

Tags: java, jvm

i was wondering what spcecifically the heap stores in its nodes? I understand a heap to be a kind of binary tree and from what I have studied of trees, the nodes contain a reference to the value stored. My question was in the case of the java heap, does the node structure contain a Java object reference to the location (stored somewhere else in RAM) of a stored object (the case a reference type), or a pointer to the memory location of the data type, or some other representation?

Reading about the subject I thought it strange that where an object is defined as a local variable, and is thus present both in the stack, as well as the heap (until I realized that this would be necissary since local variables are supposed to only be viziable to the relevent thread with the relevant thread stack) - however I still thought it odd to use a pair of object references like this and wondered perhaps whether I had misunderstood its implementation?

Comment: There is no pair of references. When you create an object, its memory is allocated in heap, and from where ever you refer it (method etc) it is just a reference( pointer to the value contained at address)

Comment: The "heap," used to refer to memory, doesn't necessarily bear a relationship to the binary heap tree you study in data structures.

Comment: The Java Memory Model refers to how a multithreaded Java program behaves and has nothing to do with how the actual memory of the JVM is structured...

Answer (score 2):

The Java heap just has to confirm to part 2.5.3 of the [VM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf). There is no single implementation, so your question does not make sense strictly speaking.

There's too little space here to fully clarify the Oracle server and client VM. You should read into it for your target VM and ask more specific questions if you get stuck.

You should compare the java stack and heap to the related concepts (stack allocation vs. malloc) in C with the difference that you do not need to free them due to GC and are not allowed to do pointer arithmetics because objects can get moved at any time.

The java memory model on the other hand prescribes what guarantees the VM has to make under concurrent access to various types of variables. Compare to C++'s `std::atomic`. This is unrelated to the memory layout.